PostgreSQL - How to INSERT with shared values in a specific column
I am creating an Exam Management System database.
I have a table called Questions:



q_id (pk)
q_text




1
What is the name of our galaxy?


2
What planet do we live on?



And a second table called Choices:



c_id (pk)
q_id (fk)
c_text




1
1
Milky Way


2
1
Galactus


3
1
Omicron Persei 8


4
2
Mars


5
2
Earth


6
2
Saturn



When I am doing an INSERT into the choices table, how can I reference the same q_id for multiple insert statements without having to write it out each time?
Similar to this:
INSERT INTO choices (q_id = 1, c_text)
VALUES ('Milky Way'),
       ('Galactus'),
       ('Omicron Persei 8');

I get this error when I try to set the column with a shared value for multiple INSERTs:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="
LINE 1: INSERT INTO choices (q_id = 1, c_text)


INSERT INTO choices (q_id, c_text)
VALUES
(1, 'Milky Way'),
(1, 'Galactus'),
(1, 'Omicron Persei 8');

q_id = 1 is not a valid column name. In the first part of the INSERT, you should mention the column names. The second part has the values

You can use an insert-select statement where you unnest an array of the values you have and have the "fixed" value as another column:
INSERT INTO choices
SELECT 1, UNNEST(ARRAY['Milky Way', 'Galactus', 'Omicron Persei 8'])

